# How to get the title and description of a channel?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-channels

I want to get the channel list description and its title like

> https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLzvCFYRLS3sJcpeaY2FECjhYOKGqW2ZDW

will show this information:

> *channel title:* top 50 english songs 2014
>
> *channel description:* pop slow romance the best (Y) top 50 songs
> arrange randomly :) hope u enjoy my first playlist

This is the link I'm using, but it doesn't contain the channel description and channel list title:

> [https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet,contentDetails&maxResults=50&pageToken=&playlistId=PLzvCFYRLS3sJcpeaY2FECjhYOKGqW2ZDW&key=[youtube-api]](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet,contentDetails&maxResults=50&pageToken=&playlistId=PLzvCFYRLS3sJcpeaY2FECjhYOKGqW2ZDW&key=%5Byoutube-api%5D)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=snippet&id=PLzvCFYRLS3sJcpeaY2FECjhYOKGqW2ZDW&key={YOUR-API-KEY}

Will get you information for a specific playlist. You can grab the `title` and `description` from the `items` that are returned.

```
"title": "top 50 english songs 2014",
"description": "pop slow romance the best (Y) top 50 songs arrange randomly :) hope u enjoy my first playlist",
```